# GtkButton with Image- align to left

Tags: gtk

I am creating a button with image on it. I would like to get it aligned left and NO GAP from margin of the button. However alhtough I aligned my button to the left of the text, there is a small "fixed" amount of gap between the image and the button border. How can I zero the gap?

Here is the code:

```
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *buttonImage;

  GtkSettings *default_settings = gtk_settings_get_default();
  g_object_set(default_settings, "gtk-button-images", TRUE, NULL);

  buttonImage = gtk_image_new();
  gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(buttonImage),"icon.jpg");

  button= gtk_button_new_with_label("Click");
  gtk_button_set_relief ((GtkButton *)button, GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
  gtk_button_set_image((GtkButton *)button, buttonImage);
  gtk_button_set_image_position((GtkButton *)button, GTK_POS_LEFT);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely some padding and/or border space being added by the theme. This gets complicated as different users may have different themes for different reasons. So it's often a good idea to leave these theme-specific settings as they are. That being said, there are situations in which you need to override these settings. For example, a text editor has tabs which have a GtkButton with a GTK_STOCK_CLOSE button. This button needs to have all padding and borders removed so that it is just the size of it's image. You can adapt this technique for your needs.

In GTK+3 this can done with GtkCssProvider and GtkStyleContext.

```
    const gchar data[] = * { "
    "-GtkButton-default-border : 0; "
    "-GtkButton-default-outside-border : 0; "
    "-GtkButton-inner-border: 0; "
    "-GtkWidget-focus-line-width : 0; "
    "-GtkWidget-focus-padding : 0; "
    "padding: 0; "
    "}";

context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (GTK_WIDGET(button));
provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider, data, -1, NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider (context,
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

That code might not be quite right, but, it should point you in the right direction. I've only implemented this technique in Python.

If you're developing for GTK+ 2, the way I used to do this was by calling calling `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` in a callback function to the "style-set" signal of the `GtkButton`.